# What is the difference between merging the trunk to a branch vs. a branch to the Trunk?

Tags: svn, merge, version-control

I am relatively new to using the `SVN` for version control. I am trying to merge the recent development on my branch to Trunk.

For sake of this example, let us suppose that my branch is at revision `r35357`. The trunk is at revision `r35486`. The common ancestral point or the point from where the branch separated is `r33285`. I am trying the following two options to understand the merge process.

**Option 1:- Merge Trunk to my branch**

I use the following steps:-

```
svn co branch_url
cd above_checked_out_repository
svn merge trunk_url
```

Here is what I get:-

1. 4 text conflicts
2. 0 tree conflicts

I would also like to mention that I do this step quite often in my branch to keep my branch updated with the `Trunk`.

**Option 2:- Merge my branch to the Trunk**

I do the following steps in this case:-

```
svn co Trunk_url
cd above_checked_out_repository
svn merge branch_url
```

Here is what I get:-

1. 84 text conflicts
2. 500 tree conflicts

Can someone please explain why these two steps behave so differently? Why the `deltas` or the total difference between two options are so different?

I also tried the following:-
After merging `Trunk` with my local copy (**Option 1**), I downloaded a fresh copy of Trunk and tried to compare the differences between the directory containing `Trunk` and `my_current_branch` using `Meld`. I got a few differences (approx 10) which is right because I added a couple of files and made changes in a few other?

Then, why the **Option2** behaves so differently and has so many differences?

Also, what exactly is a tree conflict and how to resolve them? Can someone point to an appropriate resource?

Comment: You might want to explore `git-svn` which lets you use the less rudimental mrege functionality of Git on an SVN repo. (Perhaps you will quickly conclude that Git is better worth your time anyway.)

Comment: What version of Subversion command line do you use?

Comment: @sdanil: I am using svn version 1.13.0.